# Data flow task not updating SQL Server table from oracle db

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, ssis

I am completely new to using MS Visual Studios and creating packages.

With that said, I create a package which should run SQL task editor (pulling data from a Oracle db) and then use a data flow task, using OLE DB connection, to update a table on a SQL Server.

My sql editor task uses 'sql from a variable' option which has a last run date variable included in the code (the variable `LastRunDate` that should view a field in a SQL server table for the date the package last ran successfully). Using this date it should pull Oracle db data entered after this date into the SQL Server table. The sql editor task runs fine; however, when the data flow is then called, the OLE DB Source errors out with

> [OLE DB Source [1]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.
>   An OLE DB error has occurred.
>   Error code: 0x80040E14. An OLE DB record is available.
>   Source: "Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Oracle"  Hresult: 0x80040E14
>   Description: "ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected ".

What am I not setting up appropriately?

In SQL editor task's SQL statement:

```
declare @lastRunDate datetime, @lastRunDate_AsString varchar(30), 
        @sqlScript varchar(1000);

set @lastRunDate = (SELECT LastSuccessRunDate 
                    FROM dbo.LastSuccessRunDate 
                    WHERE PackageName = 'V_M_E')

set @lastRunDate_AsString = (SELECT 
                                convert(varchar(20), @lastRunDate, 101) + '
                              ' + substring(convert(varchar(20), @lastRunDate, 9), 13, 5) + substring(convert(varchar(30), @lastRunDate, 9), 25, 2)
currentdate_time)

set @sqlScript = 'SELECT ep.member_id AS MEMBER_ID,  ep.NAME_FIRST AS
                  NAME_FIRST, ep.NAME_LAST AS NAME_LAST, ep.ADDRESS1 AS ADDRESS1, 
                  ep.ADDRESS2 AS ADDRESS2, ep.ZIP AS ZIP, ep.CITY AS CITY, ep.STATE
                  AS STATE, to_date(ep.BIRTH_DATE, ''MM/DD/YYYY'') AS BIRTH_DATE, 
                  ep.GENDER AS GENDER,  '''' AS RACE ,  '''' AS "LANGUAGE",  
                  nc.NAME_FIRST  || '' '' || nc.NAME_LAST AS EMER_CONTACT,  ep.plan AS
                  "LOB", al.affiliation_secondary AS PLAN_DESC, to_date(ep.end_date,
                  ''MM/DD/YYYY'') AS EXP_COVERAGE_DATE, ''RECIPIENT''  AS "TYPE"  
                  FROM
                       scb.ep_view ep,   SCB.N_C NC,  scb.name,  scb.afflib al 
                  WHERE
                       al.affiliation_id = sc_base.name.text3 AND sc_base.name.name_id =
nc.name_id AND nc.name_id  = ep.name_id AND
(to_date(ep.addr_update_date,''mm/dd/yyyy'') > to_date(''' +
@lastRunDate_AsString + ''', ''mm/dd/yyyy hh:miam'') OR
to_date(ep.plan_update_date,''mm/dd/yyyy'') > to_date(''' +
@lastRunDate_AsString + ''', ''mm/dd/yyyy hh:miam'')) UNION SELECT
hf.member_id AS MEMBER_ID,  hf.NAME_FIRST AS NAME_FIRST,  hf.NAME_LAST
AS NAME_LAST,  hf.ADDRESS1 AS ADDRESS1,  hf.ADDRESS2 AS ADDRESS2, 
 hf.ZIP AS ZIP,  hf.CITY AS CITY,  hf.STATE AS STATE,
to_date(hf.BIRTH_DATE, ''MM/DD/YYYY'') AS BIRTH_DATE,  hf.GENDER AS
GENDER,  '''' AS RACE ,  '''' AS "LANGUAGE",   nc.NAME_FIRST  || '' ''
|| nc.NAME_LAST AS EMER_CONTACT,  hf.plan AS "LOB",
al.affiliation_secondary AS PLAN_DESC, TO_DATE(hf.end_date,
''MM/DD/YYYY'') AS EXP_COVERAGE_DATE, ''RECIPIENT''  AS "TYPE" FROM
scb.hf_view hf,   SCB.N_C NC,  scb.name,  scb.afflib al WHERE
al.affiliation_id = sc_base.name.text3 AND sc_base.name.name_id  =
nc.name_id AND nc.name_id  = hf.name_id AND
(to_date(hf.addr_update_date,''mm/dd/yyyy'') > to_date(''' +
 @lastRunDate_AsString + ''', ''mm/dd/yyyy hh:miam'') OR
to_date(hf.plan_update_date,''mm/dd/yyyy'')  >  to_date(''' +
@lastRunDate_AsString + ''', ''mm/dd/yyyy hh:miam''))'

select @sqlScript as SQLSU
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: @marc_s Yes, I know :) I've been using the old style for so long its automatic. I definitely need to get accustomed to the "proper" way. Thanks for the link. I will review it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the FROM clause in the second sql in Union, in your dynamic sql.

This is because when you are dynamically creating sql statement, your text is getting truncated at 1000 char.

Instead of `VARCHAR(1000)` use `NVARCHAR(MAX)`

Comment: Thank you. That was the issue. Now I just have to sync the metadata columns. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Use are assigning a String that is exceeding 1000 characters to  `@sqlScript varchar(1000)`